# predict.lm after regression with missing data in Y

Tags: r, missing-data, lm, predict

I don't understand how to generate predicted values from a linear regression using the `predict.lm` command when some value of the dependent variable Y are missing, even though no independent X observation is missing. Algebraically, this isn't a problem, but I don't know an efficient method to do it in R. Take for example this fake dataframe and regression model. I attempt to assign predictions in the source dataframe but am unable to do so because of one missing Y value: I get an error.

```
# Create a fake dataframe
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(100,200,300,400,NA,600,700,800,900,100)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# Regress X and Y
model<-lm(y~x+1)
summary(model)

# Attempt to generate predictions in source dataframe but am unable to.
df$y_ip<-predict.lm(testy)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, y_ip, value = c(221.............
  replacement has 9 rows, data has 10
```

I got around this problem by generating the predictions using algebra, `df$y<-B0+ B1*df$x`, or  generating the predictions by calling the coefficients of the model `df$y<-((summary(model)$coefficients[1, 1]) + (summary(model)$coefficients[2, 1]*(df$x))` ; however, I am now working with a big data model with hundreds of coefficients, and these methods are no longer practical. I'd like to know how to do it using the `predict` function.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: the first argument of predict;lm is the model itself, not the newdata

Comment: try looking for a help file `?predict.lm` there you will see what are the necessary argument to run a function and also example.

Comment: Hi @aron if any answer solves your problem please mark it "accepted" so other people can see it

Comment: One way to solve my own problem would have been to just specify a new data frame using my x values. Continuing the code above, I could have done this: df$y_ip <- predict( object = testy, newdata = data.frame( x = df$x))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is built-in functionality for this in R (but not necessarily obvious): it's the `na.action` argument/`?na.exclude` function. With this option set, `predict()` (and similar downstream processing functions) will automatically fill in `NA` values in the relevant spots.

Set up data:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=100*(1:10))
df$y[5] <- NA
```

Fit model: default `na.action` is `na.omit`, which simply removes non-complete cases.

```
mod1 <- lm(y~x+1,data=df)
predict(mod1)
##    1    2    3    4    6    7    8    9   10 
##  100  200  300  400  600  700  800  900 1000
```

`na.exclude` removes non-complete cases before fitting, but then restores them (filled with `NA`) in predicted vectors:

```
mod2 <- update(mod1,na.action=na.exclude)
predict(mod2)
##    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
##  100  200  300  400   NA  600  700  800  900 1000
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! Your code is definitely more parsimonious than mine

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are not using correctly the `predict.lm` function. 
Either way you have to input the model itself as its first argument, hereby `model`, with or without the new data. Without the new data, it will only predict on the training data, thus excluding your `NA` row and you need this workaround to fit the initial data.frame:

```
df$y_ip[!is.na(df$y)] <- predict.lm(model)
```

Or explicitly specifying some new data. Since the new `x` has one more row than the training `x` it will fill the missing row with a new prediction:

```
df$y_ip <- predict.lm(model, newdata = df)
```